# DNS: domain2 points to domain1

Tags: domain-name-system, g-suite, godaddy

I have one domain ("domain1") that is set up with hosting and mail (hosted by Gmail Apps). This domain works perfectly.

I want a second domain ("domain2") to forward to domain1, but I don't want to use "DNS Forwarding." I would like to have it act EXACTLY like domain1, so that domain2/whatever points to the same resource as domain1/whatever WITHOUT AN HTTP REDIRECT NOR BROWSER TRICKS LIKE FRAMES. I would also love to be able to send mail to "blah@domain2" and have it go to "blah@domain1".

Can this be set up, and how? I am using GoDaddy as registrar and DNS host for both domains. GoDaddy is also the web host for domain1, and mail hosting is with Google Apps.

Comment: Point domain 2 to the same server as domain 1?

Comment: I hope your site is not important for google ;) then when you do this you have dublicate content. And its possible that your site goes down in the google ranking.

Answer (score 0):

For the web host, check to see if GoDaddy allow you to support multiple domains in your package. If they do that should solve the web site. If not you'll have to set up another package and clone the pages.

For email you'll need to visit your Google Apps control panel. Then under your domain settings add the new domain. I suspect you'll want to tick the box to make it an alias of your primary domain.